# Linq join with different types of objects avoiding the use of anonymous types in select cause

Tags: c#, linq, join, anonymous-types

Is there a way to perform a Linq Join and get my original object plus some properties of the original object to be instantiated with values from the second object, without using anonymous objects?

My original Object has too many properties and I want to perform joins with different types of objects. I do not want to use anonymous types..

Here is the ideal solution::

```
from objA in List<ClassA>
join objB in List<ClassB>
on objA.prop1 equals objB.prop2
select objA, objA.propX = objB.propY...
```

and get back objA with all its properties plus propX with new value propY..

I do not want to use anonymous types as my ClassA contains hundreds of properties and I want
to perform joins with tens of different classes...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could still use an anonymous class which passes the `ObjA` and `ObjB` as properties. You don't have to copy all of the properties of A and B.  Just `select new { objA, objB }`
What's your problem with anonymous types?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do that is to use a singular `.Join()` statement.

```cs
IEnumerable<ClassA> result =
    list.Join(
        list2,
        objA => objA.prop1,
        objB => objB.prop2,
        (objA, objB) =>
        {
            objA.propX = objB.propY;
            return objA;
        });
```